# python cluster Points with DBSCAN keeping into account Polygon boundaries

Tags: python, polygon, point, spatial-cluster, partition

I have a GeoPandas dataframe called `geo` containing:

- 431978 unique spatial Points representing all households in a city.
- 112737 Polygons representing all the premises (panden) in a city

dataframe looks like this (note that the x, y coordinates come from the Point geometry column):

[image]

I need to cluster all these Points within a 5 meter range using DBSCAN but **partitioned over the premises** so that all clustered Points **cannot** cross the boundaries of the Polygon.

So the following code produces the WRONG clustering as theoretically depicted in the screenshot:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
epsilon = 5
coords = geo[['x', 'y']].values
db = (DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric = 'euclidean')
.fit(coords))

cluster_labels = db.labels_
unique_labels = set(cluster_labels)
# number of clusters
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))
print ('number of clustered verblijfsobjecten: 
{}'.format(num_clusters))
```

[image]

The right DBSCAN cluster assignment, again, would take into a count the boundaries of the Polygons that the clustered Points CANNOT cross. So to depict the right clustering for one of the premises:

[image]

I assume assigning the DBSCAN algorithm on each group resulting from the `geo.groupby(['pand_id'])` and `get_group` method, would be a way to go ?

In SQL this is easy but my question is how to do this in Python/sklearn. thnx!

SQL statement:

```
Q = """drop table if exists TABLE.SCHEMA;
create table service_afvalcontainers.stag_vo_cluster as
select
    pand_id,
    ST_X(geometrie) x,
    ST_Y(geometrie) y,
    ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geometrie,5,1) over(PARTITION BY pand_id) as 
    cluster,
    geometrie    
from
    TABLE.SCHEMA bla bla
```

;
"""
UPDATED ANSWER PART: In Python I tried:

```
### get pand_id to feed into loop. 
unique_pand_id = geo.pand_id.unique().tolist()

coords_frame = []
for pand in unique_pand_id[:10]:
coords = (geo.loc[geo['pand_id'] == pand, ('index' ,'pand_id' ,'verblijfsobject_id', 'x', 'y')].values)
coords_frame.append(coords) 

cluster_label_frame = []
epsilon=5
for elem in [[elem[3:5] for elem in group] for group in coords_frame]:
db = (DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric = 'euclidean')
 .fit(elem))
cluster_labels = db.labels_
cluster_label_frame.append(cluster_labels)
```

This `cluster_label_frame` looks ok indeed but the thing is, I need to have these cluster_ids and attach them back onto the original `geo` dataframe. I probably need to add the geo index to this label_frame with which I can hopefully join back to the `geo` frame. It doens' t feel like the right approach but it`s a step further...

[image]

Comment: So you now want to use those labels and add it as a value of each point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a good approach would be to separate your points by `pand_id` and then run DBSCAN for each of those.

To filter your dataframe depending on the content of the `pand_id` column you can use the `.loc[]` feature, for example:

```
geo.loc[geo['pand_id'] == 123]
```

This will yield all the elements on your dataset that have `123` on their `pand_id` column.

Furthermore, if the `pand_id` values vary greatly, and thus knowing them explicitly might be a problem, you can obtain the unique values on your column with:

```
geo['pand_id'].unique()
```

You can then iterate over those values, filter with `.loc[]`, obtain X,Y values or whatever you need and proceed with the DBSCAN algorithm.

Comment: thnx. It seems like something to explore. I updated my question (see part as from UPDATED ANSWER PART. Almost there. Now it is tricky to merge this back into the geo dataframe

Comment: @ad_s glad I could help, although what you edited is a separate question in my opinion. This answer addresses your original problem, if you now have another I suggest you post a separate question. You are now talking more about pandas, which could be better fit on SO.